# Fixing package install wants to remove packges

Tags: package-management

I have installed the drivers for a scanner, but Ubuntu complained that there were missing packages and to solve this problem I used to command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

but now Ubuntu wants to remove some packages I need like dropbox and chrome:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git-man liberror-perl libtokyocabinet9 regina-normal-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libhogweed5 libnettle7 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsmbclient
  libsystemd0 libudev1 libwbclient0 samba-libs systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd udev
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  brscan-skey cupswrappermfc7360n:i386 forticlient-sslvpn git
  google-chrome-stable libc6-dbg nautilus-dropbox regina-normal skypeforlinux
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libhogweed5 libnettle7 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsmbclient
  libsystemd0 libudev1 libwbclient0 samba-libs systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd udev
13 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
```

How do I fix the broken install without removing the packages I need?

**EDIT** I use version 20.04 LTS.

The drivers I have installed are for the scanner and printer MFC-7360N. The instruction I followed came from the official site of the Brother company: [here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc7360n_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006239_000&flang=4&type3=561).

Comment: You've provided no release details, are the packages intended for your release?  Dependency issues are usually caused by poor prior (esp. forced `-f`) commands & incorrect sources & *lack of homework* to ensure packages are correct. You've provided no specifics as to your release, or your sources, but issues shouldn't occur when all are built for the same release.

Comment: @guiverc see my edit